# Identity Server 4 with EF identity DB - OpenID Connect Failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

PLEASE NOTE: This issue was not resolved in this post.  I was asked to create a new post.  Please refer to the new post titled:

Identity Server 4 with EF identity DB - OpenID Connect Failing (1)

I have an Identity Server 4 solution with EF Identity DB. I can login with my email and external gmail account, but when I try to login using OpenID (User name and Password) I receive the error below. The issue maybe with the info stored in the Identity DB tables. I'm new to Identity Server and this is my first attempt working with EF Identity DB. I can post DB info if it helps resolve the issue.

Source code:
https://github.com/gotnetdude/GotNetDude-PublicRepository/tree/master/AuthServer

Identity Server Log File:
https://github.com/gotnetdude/GotNetDude-PublicRepository/blob/master/AuthServer_log.txt

MVC Client Log:
https://github.com/gotnetdude/GotNetDude-PublicRepository/blob/master/MVCClient_log.txt

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Paul

**EDIT**

Please find below the Client configuration info from the identity tables.  I'm not sure where to set the AllowedRedirectUris in the DB. The other question I have is why does it work when I sign-in with my email account?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the AuthServer Startup code where I add oidc mvc client as the challenge option ("OpenID Connect") which is fail.  The MVC client works fine if I login with the email credentials.  I guess is that this has some to do with the way the scope is being handled on the mvc client.  Any suggestion are appreciated.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "434483408261-55tc8n0cs4ff1fe21ea8df2o443v2iuc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "3gcoTrEDPPJ0ukn_aYYT6PWo";
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
                {
                    //options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/";
                    //options.ClientId = "implicit";
                    //options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.ClientId = "mvc";

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        RoleClaimType = "role"
                    };
                });
```

I'm trying to connect to authority (:5000) from the MVC Client (:5002) see image below:
[image]

Debug results from AccountService:
[image]

There are 3 instances IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.Client in the client store under context, clients.  All 3 instances had there EnableLocalLogin set to True. I hit the break point after selecting OpenID Connect option.

I also set a breakpoint at the top of the login controller, which it never reached:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.   I new to this... Appreciate the advice.

Comment: Don't debug the constructor of `AccountService` . Debug `BuildLoginViewModelAsync` method, and check what happens at the end. I just saw it is commented out in your code. Why is that?

Comment: The question is becoming unclear as new questions and information that is not related to the original question is added. This is not a working document. Please remove all information / questions that are not related to the original question and start a new question. If any of the answers did answer your original question then mark it as answer.

Comment: The AccountService _account is constructed  in line 52 of the AccountController.  The _account is only being referenced at line 270 of the AccountController for logout purposes.  AccountService is not being used for Input as far as I can tell.  This was code that is part of the Quick Start Sample code.

Comment: I'm being asked to post another new question regarding this issue.  Not sure I will edit my original question pointing you to the new question.  Let me know if there is a better way to do this...  Thanks Paul

Answer (score 0):

Check the Log files that you have provided. The error that you are receiving is

> Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc.

If you check your client configuration your `AllowedRedirectUris` contains `http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc`.

You have a (typo) mistake in the port. It must be `5002`.

**EDIT**

According to your screenshots, and to the log files, your client is properly configured on the Identity Server side. The problem is in your MVC client, not in the database. You need to look there, and find what `RedirectUrl` you are setting when starting the client itself.

**EDIT 2:**

OK, after looking at your code I realized that what @Ruard van Elburg is telling you is the reason for having this problem. When using the Internal authentication, you don't need to specify it like this (you are really confusing Identity Server). This specification is for external Oidc provider only (for example Okta, or whatever else Oidc provider you have). Check [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html). You see - the Identity Server `Startup.cs` doesn't contain this code that you have (line 74 to 89 [here](https://github.com/gotnetdude/GotNetDude-PublicRepository/blob/daa56d5605e071959f7c5d67a543c07496eeacaf/AuthServer/AuthServer/Startup.cs#L74)). Why don't we do this step by step. Try with removing the lines that I mentioned.

Comment: Please see the EF identity DB tables I posted above.  I could be wrong, but I feel like this is a client config issue.  I'm using mvc client to login with the email and that works fine, but when I select the OpenID Connect challenge login option the mvc client is failing.  The email (oidc) login uses the api scope to authenticate.  What credentials does the "OpenID Connect" mvc client need to authenticate?

Comment: @Paul - please stop trying to edit my answer - instead either add a comment, or edit your question. Otherwise it becomes a mess. Now to the question - debug the `AccountService.cs` and the `AccountController.cs` and check the LoginViewModel. What is the value of `EnableLocalLogin`? If it is false - don't expect to see the local login option on the login screen

Comment: Okay... I added the test result to my original question.

Comment: m3n7alsnak3 -  Appreciate your contributions... I'm sure you're right about this having to with AccountServices commented out code.  I've been attempting to get the code to work to no avail to this point.  The reason I'm need to get the login user to work is because I would like to setup signal signin using the company I work for LDAP info.  I hope you can continue to assist me with resolving this issue.  Please refer to the new question.  I will be tracking the problem from there... Paul

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in line [74](https://github.com/gotnetdude/GotNetDude-PublicRepository/blob/master/AuthServer/AuthServer/Startup.cs#L74) from AuthServer/Startup:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
    {
        ...
        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        ...
    });
```

The *server* is not the *mvc client*. I think this is 'confusing' IdentityServer. You don't need to add oidc to the server. If you remove theses lines then it should work.

If you login from the mvc client website (:5002) then you should be redirected. And if you login to IdentityServer (:5000) you don't have to be redirected. The server is the authority, the resource is identified by a scope and the client by a clientid.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I updated my post with an image of the MVC Client page with the OpenID Connect challenge option.  It's not my intention to remove this option, so I will plan to keep it in the AuthSever (:5000) Startup class.  Since the mvc client works with the email credentials, maybe I need to configure another client (mvc.openid) which that has the proper credential assigned to it like scope?

Comment: Move comments above

Comment: You can only solve the issue by removing the lines. Then the question is what you are trying to achieve and why you think you need these lines.